# Apache spawning one process a day, what causes it?

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I have a PHP server running, with cron jobs etc...
And once a day (between midnight and 3am), apache spawns one process that never ends. The server is a virtual server, so in a couple of days it eats up the whole memory.

Is there a way to figure out what is crashing ? What php script isn't finishing ? Or what url via apache was triggered ?

I have tried looking on the access logs, errors logs, but didn't find anything unusual.

Thank you

Comment: How do you know its started between midnight and 3am?  Fact you seem to see one a day suggests its one of those CRON scripts.  Do you do any logging with those?  Sounds like a narrow enough field to find which one it is.

Comment: also 'lsof' command can be very useful to look what files has opened the proces

Comment: I have ran "ps -aux" to see what time each process started, and each of the processes began between midnight and 3am.

I have tried lsof, but haven't seen any useful information inside :(.

Comment: Please add more details: Version of apache-httpd, what is your operating system, is the httpd part of your operating system, how did you install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for **/proc/$PID** of that suspicious httpd-process and look into **environ** and **cmdline**. Do an `ls -Fal` of the **fd** subdirectory to see its active file-handles.

If this does not ring a bell - post the results as edit to your question.

Comment: Using your method I saw that there was a log file open inside fd with warnings inside for tomcat. I don't use tomcat, the only module I need is PHP. I also saw it loads Python etc... I disabled useless modules and I'll see how it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling mod_status: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html

This will allow you to connect the PID and a request path of the offending script, and is also useful in just general admin.

If that's not enough to track down the culprit you might want to add a few logging statements to your jobs to help you track down where the script is looping and/or dying, or even attach a debugger if that tickles your fancy.

Also, like Jarry suggested, you can use lsof to determine what files/connections the process currently has open, which may give you a clue as to what it is trying to do.